# In ArcGis 10, spatial join of a hot street value to a fishnet cell is counting multiple values for same street segment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-joins, vector-grid

So, I am working on a fishnet, so that we can attribute multiple values to points within different cells (i.e., ranking light poles as optimum for traffic cameras based on the number of speeding tickets, accidents, etc) so that all poles in a high value cell would be ranked as prime candidates.

To do this, we have assigned numerical counts of accidents to street segments (sections between intersections) and are attempting to join those values to the fishnet through a spatial join. The issue is, if a street segment runs through the cell, and has a value of 5, it is counted 15 times (or whatever for each cell) and the cell then has a value of 75 instead of 5). Any way to fix this and get one value from each unique street segment in the cell?

(averaging as a run around doesn't work, as some cells have different street segments and if one street has a 0, we don't want that to discount the value of the other street that may have a higher value.) We've tried dissolving, interection, multi to single, and none of them seem to make each street segment unique or with only the requisite value display once.

Here is a shot of the image. the issue is, and this example actually accidentally illustrated it clearer than I'd seen, is that for the horizontal street near the middle, with a "3" (there are only two dots because one has 2 values) looks correct, but if one tried to join that "3" value to a cell intersecting that street segment, it would likely join the value "45." This is demonstrated a street over where one street has a "3" a "0" and a "7." This seems to demonstrate the single street is actually 3 segments to arcgis. I can't figure out how to make, for example, that street equal "10" and then join it's value to a cell so the cell would only have "10" as the joined value, not "30" or "150" or however many times it joined.

[image: map example]

Comment: Could you perhaps include a diagram illustrating your issue?  If that had the result you observe vs the result you expect, then I think it would help clarify the issue for me and others.

Comment: image added, let me know if it helped explain the issue. My best guess is I need a way to make each street segment between intersections one segment so it's value is only transferred once.